# How can I connect to Memgraph from my C# application?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have data stored in dockerized Memgraph database. How can I connect from my C# app to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Neo4j.Driver.Simple` package which implements a blocking interface around the 'main' driver.

Once you have the latest version of driver installed you can connect to your database using one of the ways.

First way:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Neo4j.Driver;

namespace MemgraphApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string message = "Hello, World!";

            using var _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.None);
            using var session = _driver.Session();

            var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
            {
                var result = tx.Run("CREATE (n:FirstNode) " +
                                    "SET n.message = $message " +
                                    "RETURN 'Node '  + id(n) + ': ' + n.message",
                    new { message });
                return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
            });
            Console.WriteLine(greeting);
        }
    }
}
```

Second way:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Neo4j.Driver;

namespace MemgraphApp
{
    public class Program : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IDriver _driver;

        public Program(string uri, string user, string password)
        {
            _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
        }

        public void PrintGreeting(string message)
        {
            using (var session = _driver.Session())
            {
                var greeting = session.WriteTransaction(tx =>
                {
                    var result = tx.Run("CREATE (n:FirstNode) " +
                                        "SET n.message = $message " +
                                        "RETURN 'Node '  + id(n) + ': ' + n.message",
                        new { message });
                    return result.Single()[0].As<string>();
                });
                Console.WriteLine(greeting);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _driver?.Dispose();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var greeter = new Program("bolt://localhost:7687", "", ""))
            {
                greeter.PrintGreeting("Hello, World!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Detailed instructions can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/c-sharp.